# how to print FlippedTriangle pattern using python

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code but it is not working as expected

```
def printFlippedTriangle(width):
  for i in range(0, width):
    for J in range(0, width-i):
      print(" ", end=" ")  # single line
      for j in range(0,i):
         print(" "+"* ", end=" ")  # single line
         j=j-1
    print("*")
```

Am getting this:

```
                   *
        *     *     *     *  *
      *   *     *   *     *   *  *
      *   *   *     *   *   *  *
      *   *   *   *  *
```

am suppose to get:

```
            * 
         *  * 
      *  *  * 
   *  *  *  * 
*  *  *  *  *
```

Any idea and or suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Think through what you are doing with your different indices. Try labelling on a piece of paper a grid and your points (the *s) and count through the code that you have written....Homework can be fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the job done, and in a single loop too!

```
def triangle(w):
    for i in range(0, w):
        print(' ' * ((w - i - 1) * 2), end='') # spaces for each row
        print('* ' * (i + 1), end='') # * for each row
        print() # new line

>>> triangle(5)
        * 
      * * 
    * * * 
  * * * * 
* * * * *
```

Each row needs `width - rowNumber - 1` spaces and `rowNumber + 1` asterisks when starting from `0`